# How can I create a lstlisting environment that spans more than one page?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I am using `listings` package to show some algorithms in a LaTeX document.

One of the algorithms I want to include is longer than one page. So, my question is:

How can I create a `lstlisting` environment that spans more than one page??

Comment: Could you add the start of the `lstlisting` environment that gives problems?

Comment: It can spans more than one pages.

Comment: do not use the `float` option of the environment `lstlisting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{pstricks.tex}
\end{document}
```

can spans multiple pages:

[image]

Please delete this answer if I forget to do so.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. My problem was I was using `float` option.

Comment: How did you do this `.gif`?

Comment: @Sigur: Please visit my profile, and locate the most bottom link. It is explained there.